# lucene .net fuzzy multiple words

Tags: lucene, lucene.net

I want combined fuzzy search on two terms , eg:- 'magikal~0.8' and  'mistery'~0.8, should return the results where words 'magical' and 'mystery' both are there.

My current code is as follows

```
Directory createIndex(DataTable table)
        {
            var directory = new RAMDirectory();

            using (Analyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(Lucene.Net.Util.Version.LUCENE_30))
            using (var writer = new IndexWriter(directory, analyzer, new IndexWriter.MaxFieldLength(1000)))
            {
                foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
                {
                    var document = new Document();
                    document.Add(new Field("DishName", row["DishName"].ToString(), Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED));
                    document.Add(new Field("CustomisationID", row["CustomisationID"].ToString(), Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.NOT_ANALYZED));

                    writer.AddDocument(document);
                }

                writer.Optimize();
                writer.Flush(true, true, true);
            }
            return directory;
        }

private DataTable SearchDishName(string textSearch)
        {
            string MatchingCutomisationIDs = "0"; //There is no Dish with ID zero, this is just to easen the coding.. 
            var ds = new DataSet();
            ds.ReadXml(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_data/MyDataset.xml"));
            DataTable Sample = new DataTable();
            Sample = ds.Tables[0];
            var table = Sample.Clone();
            var Index = createIndex(Sample);
            using (var reader = IndexReader.Open(Index, true))
            using (var searcher = new IndexSearcher(reader))
            {
                using (Analyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(Lucene.Net.Util.Version.LUCENE_30))
                {
                    var queryParser = new QueryParser(Lucene.Net.Util.Version.LUCENE_30, "DishName", analyzer);
                    var collector = TopScoreDocCollector.Create(1000, true);
                    try
                    {
                        var query = queryParser.Parse(textSearch);
                        searcher.Search(query, collector);
                    }
                    catch
                    { }
                    var matches = collector.TopDocs().ScoreDocs;
                    foreach (var item in matches)
                    {
                        var id = item.Doc;
                        var doc = searcher.Doc(id);
                        var row = table.NewRow();
                        row["CustomisationID"] = doc.GetField("CustomisationID").StringValue;
                        table.Rows.Add(row);
                    }
                }
            }
            return table;
        }
```

Also another issue with this code is that. If I run a normal query with an && operator it still don't get the accurate results
eg :- results for the query "magical"&&"mystery", includes cases where only "magical" or only "mystery" is there.